# Ionic 3 Angular 5 ion-select tag not able to set Default Value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Code snippet.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label> Day</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="day"  >
        <ion-option value="Monday">Monday</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Thursday">Thursday</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Friday">Friday</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Saturday">Saturday</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Sunday">Sunday</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
   </ion-item>
```

I just need to set Monday as the default value selected.

Comment: TS: `day = 'Monday';`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label> Day</ion-label>
<ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="day"  >
    <ion-option value="Monday">{{'Monday' | translate}}</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Tuesday">{{'Tuesday' | translate}}</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Wednesday">{{'Wednesday' | translate}}</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Thursday">{{'Thursday' | translate}}</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Friday">{{'Friday' | translate}}</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Saturday">{{'Saturday' | translate}}</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Sunday">{{'Sunday' | translate}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

When we use both @ngx-translate and ngModel, it doesn't work well like this issue.